# Openshift 4 ConfigMap binary file is mounted as directory

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, configmap

I have created ConfigMap from Openshift 4 Windows 10 CLI:

```
.\oc create configmap my-cacerts --from-file=cacerts
```

I can see ConfigMap with name **my-cacerts** and download binary file **cacerts** from it using web interface of Openshift 4

Now I mount it (part of **my-deployment.yaml**)

```
containers:
  volumeMounts:
    - name: my-cacerts-volume
      mountPath: /etc/my/cacerts
volumes:
  - name: my-cacerts-volume
    config-map: 
      name: my-cacerts
```

Unfortunately */etc/my/cacerts* is mounted as a empty folder but not as a single binary file.

How can I mount **cacerts** as a file and not as a directory?

**Update:**

If I issue

```
.\oc get configmap my-cacerts
```

There is following output:

```
apiVersion: v1
binaryData:
  cacerts: ... big long base64...
kind: ConfigMap
metadata: ...
```

If I issue

```
.\oc describe pod my-pod
```

I get

```
Volumes:
  my-cacerts-volume:
    Type: EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Openshift 4 **defaultMode** should be specified:

```
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /etc/my
          name: cacerts-ref
          readOnly: true
  volumes:
    - name: cacerts-ref
      configMap:
        defaultMode: 420
        name: cacerts
```

After that **configMap** contents are mapped correctly.

```
.\oc describe pod my-pod

Volumes:
  cacerts-ref:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
Name:      cacerts
Optional:  false
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `volumes` definition is incorrect, `config-map` **does not exist and is invalid**, but it seems the API is silently falling back to an `EmptyDir` here, thus leading to an empty directory.

When you create a `ConfigMap` using the `oc` command above, the result will be a `ConfigMap` that looks like this (note that there is one key called "cacerts"):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-cacerts
data:
  cacerts: |
    Hello world!
```

In the `volumes` section, then use `configMap:` together with `subPath` as follows to mount a only a single key ("cacerts") from your `ConfigMap`:

```
$ oc edit deployment my-deployment
[..]
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: registry.fedoraproject.org/fedora-minimal:33
        name: fedora-minimal
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /etc/my/cacerts
          name: my-cacerts-volume
          subPath: cacerts
[..]
      volumes:
      - configMap:
          name: my-cacerts
          defaultMode: 420
        name: my-cacerts-volume
```

This then results in:

```
$ oc rsh ...
sh-5.0$ ls -l /etc/my/cacerts
-rw-r--r--. 1 root 1000590000 13 Dec  3 19:11 /etc/my/cacerts
sh-5.0$ cat /etc/my/cacerts
Hello world!
```

You can also leave `subPath` out and set `/etc/my/` as the destination for the same result, as for each key there will be a file:

```
[..]
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /etc/my/
          name: my-cacerts-volume
[..]
      volumes:
      - configMap:
          name: my-cacerts
        name: my-cacerts-volume
```

For the right syntax, you can also check [the documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/builds/builds-configmaps.html#builds-configmaps-use-case-consuming-in-volumes_builds-configmaps)

Comment: Hi Simon, thanks for fast answer. I will try it right now. Please note that if I issue "oc get configmap my-cacerts -o yaml" then I get yaml containing all the stuff, but there is binaryData instead of data inside. It is Openshift 4

Comment: I have tried it one-to-one (incl. oc rsh), but it still creates empty folder. As mentioned before the only difference is that inside ConfigMap I have binaryData: caccerts: >- ...

Comment: Thanks for updating your original question. BinaryData or Data in your ConfigMap should not matter, that should work in both cases. The main issue is that you still have a volume of type „Type: EmptyDir“, you should edit the Deployment again to get that right and make sure you get the correct volume type there (also see the docs I linked).

Comment: It was Openshift specific stuff, defaultMode: 420 has solved my problem